# Swift TextField has no width

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have just started learning swift and have been trying to create a layout using the scoreboard.

I have placed two textfields and set the constraints properly using the document outline. However when I run the emulator the Text Fields display wrong.

I have attached a screenshot, The left is what happens in my emulator the right is what I see in the view editor in xCode
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I would of embedded the image but I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: because you used wrong constraints....

Comment: Please also upload a screenshot of the constraints which you have set, The screenshot you currently have is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the wrong constraints.....as you give x and y position to edges of the screen you can not maintain the width of the textview...

ok here is some images ...just follow it...

[image]

[image]

In first image i just give x and y position with height and width to first textfield and in the second one i give equal width and heigh to first one.

Comment: To add to this answer: Please try to avoid setting the width to a hard value on Any-Any. Make the view and add hard values in specific size classes. Maybe you could set the width to be at >= a certain value; set the distances from the edges to be >= standard and set the width of the textfield to be proportional to the width of the superview, maybe 75%. Then adjust your priorities so on a small screen it uses the ones on the edges; on a bigger screen it uses the max width; everything in between is 75% of the device width.

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong constraints. You set it so its constant inset from the two sides. If the screen gets small, the constant inset stays the same and it squeezes the `textField`.

You want to keep a constant width of the `textField` so no matter what size the screen is, it will keep the constant width.